# Getting access to an element in ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I want to access the current image url (the url is a property of the image object) in the ngFor loop that loops through an array of image objects. I want to access this in same components typescript file.

I though that maybe I could bind to  property in the same components .ts file using the @Input() but I believe this is for a child/parent relationship.

How would I go about doing this in angular?

Relevant html:

```
<div
      class="image-container"
      *ngFor="let image of galleryList"
      [imageUrl]="image.Url">

</div
```

Relevant ts code:

```
  @Input() imageUrl: string;
```

I am not expecting the above code to work but I just wanted to show you what I am trying to achieve.

Ultimately, I am trying to use the image url in this method within the typescript file:

```
checkLike(imageUrl: string): boolean {
    const users = this.usersService.getUsers();

    if(this.isLoggedIn) {
      const currUsersIndex = this.usersService.getCurrUserArrIndex();
      console.log(currUsersIndex);
      const FavouritesList = users[currUsersIndex].likes;

      if(FavouritesList.includes(imageUrl)) {
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }
    }
```

Then conditionally add html elements depending on the result:

```
 <div *ngIf="checkLike(image.imagePath)" class="heart-icon-container">
        <ion-icon name="heart" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!checkLike(image.imagePath)" class="heart-icon-container">
        <ion-icon name="heart-outline" class="heart-icon" (click)="updateLike(image.imagePath)"></ion-icon>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have a component abc-component, you can go with it like

```
<abc-component *ngFor="let image of galleryList" [imageUrl]="image.Url"></abc-component>
```

But you can't pass inputs to normal div, unless you change selector of your component as a attribute, For eg:-

```
@Component({
  selector: [abc-component],
   ....
  })
```

Then you can use it like :-

```
<div *ngFor="let image of galleryList" [imageUrl]="image.Url" abc-component></div>
```

And have it inside Abc component like

```
@Input() imageUrl: string;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need access to the image Url in the typescript file, not the html file. Ultimately what I am trying to do is use the image url in a method in the typescript file

Comment: on what event you want it?

Comment: when this checkLike Method will fire?

Comment: you should never call a method inside ngIf, that will cause harm to performance.

Comment: The other thing I was trying to do was to update a boolean variable in the typescript code and then use this is the *ngIf statement but I still need to get access to the imageUrl on the typescript code.

Comment: see you have a ng for on div. on what event to which method you want to pass this url? until you tell that, its a invalid question actually. lets say you wanted it on click of div, you could do it like <div (click)="myMethod(image.imageURL)"></div>

Comment: I am trying to use the image url in the checkLike method as explained above

Comment: if this div is inside that div with ngFor loop, yes you can pass it like this.